# How to retrieve data in sqlite using where clause?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have imported data from CSV file to SQLite table.
When I try to retrieve record using a specific column, it returns 0 records. Whereas, data is present
in the table.
The schema of the table:

```
public static final class Vehicle2Wheel implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="Vehicle2Wheel";
    public static final String VEH_ID = "VEH_ID";
    public static final String VEH_REG_NUM = "VEH_REG_NUM";
    public static final String VEH_ENGINE_NO = "VEH_ENGINE_NO";
    public static final String VEH_CHASIS_NO= "VEH_CHASIS_NO";
    public static final String VEH_MAKE= "VEH_MAKE";
    public static final String VEH_CC = "VEH_CC";
    public static final String VEH_COLOR = "VEH_COLOR";
    public static final String VEH_MODEL = "VEH_MODEL";
    public static final String OWN_NAME = "OWN_NAME";
    public static final String OWN_FNAME = "OWN_FNAME";
    public static final String CNIC = "OWN_CNIC";
    public static final String OWN_ADDRESS = "OWN_ADDRESS";
}
```

The creation of table:

```
String tableVeh2Wheel = "CREATE TABLE "+ Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.TABLE_NAME+
            " ("+ Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_ID+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_REG_NUM+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_ENGINE_NO+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_CHASIS_NO+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_MAKE+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_CC+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_COLOR+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.VEH_MODEL+ " TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.OWN_NAME+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.OWN_FNAME+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.CNIC+" TEXT,"
            + Schema.Vehicle2Wheel.OWN_ADDRESS+" TEXT"
            + ");";
```

The code to import data from CSV file:

```
public void setData(String filePath, String tableName, int colCount, String[] colNames){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);

    try {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(filePath);

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        String line = "";
        db.beginTransaction();

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] str = line.split(",",colCount);

            int length = str.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                contentValues.put(colNames[i], str[i].toString());
            }


            db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (db.inTransaction())
            db.endTransaction();

        Toast.makeText(context,""+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (db.inTransaction())
        db.endTransaction();
}
```

This code(Code 1) returns cursor count zero:
**Code 1:**

```
database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String vehId = "";
        try {
            String value = "KIL-3396";
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT VEH_ID FROM Vehicle2Wheel WHERE VEH_REG_NUM=?", new String[] {value + ""});
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                vehId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VEH_ID"));
                Log.v(TAG,"Vehicle ID is "+vehId);
            }else
                Log.v(TAG,"no record, size of cursor is "+cursor.getCount());

        }finally {
            cursor.close();

        }
```

The output of this code is shown in picture p1[image: picture p1]

Whereas, this(below) code return reg number "KIL-3396". Which means that this record is present in the table, 
but why it is not retrieve using code (i.e Code 1). Why is reg number "KIL-3396" not matched? 
Data is not retrieved using any column except VEH_ID.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Vehicle2Wheel LIMIT 5;";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (mcursor.getCount()>0) {
        mcursor.moveToFirst();
        while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mcursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Data is " + mcursor.getString(i));

            }
        }
    }
```

output of this code is shown in picture p2[image: picture p2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that if you change the second code to be :-

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Vehicle2Wheel LIMIT 5;";
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (mcursor.getCount()>0) {
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mcursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Data is " + mcursor.getString(i));

        }
    }
}

Cursor cursor = null;
String vehId = "";
try {
    String value = "KIL-3396";
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT VEH_ID FROM Vehicle2Wheel WHERE VEH_REG_NUM=?", new String[] {value + ""});
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        vehId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VEH_ID"));
        Log.v(TAG,"Vehicle ID is "+vehId);
    } else
        Log.v(TAG,"no record, size of cursor is "+cursor.getCount());

    }finally {
        cursor.close();

    }
```

That you will obtain the expected results. i.e. it is the position/location/order of code 1 that is the issue and from the supplied code the specific issue cannot be determined.

#### Testing your code I get :-

> ```
> 06-02 22:21:00.399 1672-1672/va.vehicleapp V/SEARCHACTIVITY: Vehicle ID is 3
>     Data is 3
>     Data is KIL-3396
>     Data is 12345678
>     Data is 12345678
>     Data is Suzuki
>     Data is 125
>     Data is Red
>     Data is GL
>     Data is FrederickSon
>     Data is Fred
>     Data is 12345678
>     Data is 1 The Fred, Fredickstown
> ```

- In the test I have made up data, with the exception of the REG Number (2 rows, note that moveToFirst skips the first row son only 1 row is shown)

The following code was used for testing :-

```
private void lookAtRecords(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String TAG = "SEARCHACTIVITY";


    Cursor cursor = null;
    String vehId = "";
    try {
        String value = "KIL-3396";
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT VEH_ID FROM Vehicle2Wheel WHERE VEH_REG_NUM=?", new String[] {value + ""});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            vehId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VEH_ID"));
            Log.v(TAG,"Vehicle ID is "+vehId);
        }else
            Log.v(TAG,"no record, size of cursor is "+cursor.getCount());

    }finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Vehicle2Wheel LIMIT 5;";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (mcursor.getCount()>0) {
        mcursor.moveToFirst();
        while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mcursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Data is " + mcursor.getString(i));

            }
        }
    }
}
```